# Webcomic about cute demons

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

Anybody know what webcomic this is from?  Slightly different from the usual "what's that story" question, but all I have to go off of is this one image, and Google Images search yields nothing.

[image: cute demons webcomic]

For helping other searches, I guess, here's what I know, in text form:

- Characters appear to be demons or something;
- primarily black silhouettes with orange accents, like glowing eyes.

Transcript of the snippet I have reads as follows:

> Kid: "I am suff'rin' from tiny leg syndrome.  I require services."
>
> Adult: "Piggy backs?"
>
> Kid: "Yish."

Comment: Assuming you're using chrome, If you right-click on the image and click "search Google for image", you'll find your answer in fairly short order...; https://themiskatonicgame.tumblr.com/post/110365906812/head-on-over-to-kickstarter-to-check-it-out-here

Comment: @Valorum ...Ah.  I checked google image search, but somehow had a blind spot for the line that read "Pages that include matching images".  Thanks!  If you want to make that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I recognize the artist and project. I used to read *Redd* and *Chimneyspeak* before they got rather blatantly NSFW.

Comment: @Erhannis - Teach a man to fish. Why don't you self-answer now you've got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The Miskatonic](https://store.steampowered.com/app/870290/The_Miskatonic/), a Lovecraftian game on Steam.

I was apparently insufficiently alert the first time I tried Google Image Search - there's a section at the bottom specifically labeled "Pages that include matching images", which I overlooked.

Comment: Glad you found it! You can accept your own answer.